# How many computers are there?

Tags: computer-science, computers, technology

There are about [7.13 billion humans alive today](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=world%20population).

When installing Java, it says that 3 billion devices run Java.  The question is, out of how many?  How many computing devices that have enough hardware to run Java will be on at some point on a non-holiday Tuesday?

Servers count, smartphones count, and if you see a clear way to refine the definition in the question please feel free to propose an edit or state the slightly different definition in your answer.

Comment: I heard somewhere that General Motors is now the number 1 seller of computers.  I wonder how many computers are in each car...

Comment: And this is about history because?

Comment: It establishes a particular point in the spread of computing technology, which implements a lot of science and math.  Also, I anticipate that it'll be hard to come up with an answer for *today* but any answer is likely to be somewhat historical, or maybe even a set of historical points.  History of computing & computer science seem on topic here, and more so here than anywhere else (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Do smartcards (e.g. SIM cards) count?

Comment: @MartinSchröder I would tend to think not, but could be convinced otherwise by a good answer/definition that does count them.

Comment: @WBT: Actually most SIM cards can (and do) run Java. :-)

Comment: Do digital cameras count as computers?  Calculators?  Fitbits? Televisions? Microwave ovens? Smart phones?  Dumb phones?  (My flip phone runs Java.)  LED lightbulbs? Electronic thermostats?  Gas/water/power meters? Traffic signals? Barcode scanners? Credit-card scanners? Electronic door locks? Remote-control helicopters? Electronic musical instruments? Digital movie projectors? How many computers are in an automobile?

Comment: @JeffE any answer with a clear and consistent definition is fine by me; the question's hard enough without my arbitrarily overconstraining it. My intuition would be to generally require a general purpose processing unit, power electronics, input, and output; "can run Java" as a guide. By that, at least some LEDs & lightbulbs would be out of the count; a traffic light might be out but a control computer in, and a car's main computers would be in but not the little chip in a window switch. Upvotes & downvotes on answers should reward clear & consistent definitions & answers that fit.

Comment: In my last comment, by "input" and "output" I meant *for information* and a network interface can be both.  I think of a sensor (in at least many cases) as being just an input device for another machine and suggest that a barcode scanner or other kind of scanner that just functions as an input device to a more general computer (like at a department store checkout counter) would not count as one on its own, but e.g. the complete device that a theatre usher uses to scan tickets and check their validity against some central system probably does count.